# Intercept clipboard changes

Tags: c++, windows, clipboard

how it is possible to generally intercept clipboard changes in C++? E.g. I would like to write a Windows Service that intercepts any Ctrl-C. Is it possible? How?

Thank you in advance.

James

Comment: Note that there are many ways to update the clipboard without using Ctrl+C.  Eugene is correct, you want to write a windows clipboard viewer. Techniques for notification differ from XP and Vista/Windows7.  Be sure to follow ALL of the rules, or you'll end up causing conflicts with other apps that also monitor the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a "windows clipboard hook". Google search on this term gives plenty of information, for example, [this library on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/WindowsHookLib.aspx), which seems to fit your requirements.